# Steam family sharing shows “buy” instead of “play”

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing, arma-3

So my friend let me try out Arma 3 by adding my account to family sharing. So he logged onto his account on my PC (Using TeamViewer) and added my account to family sharing, and while logged into his account, I downloaded Arma 3. The next morning, I logged out of his account, went onto mine and Arma 3 was there downloaded in my account but it had the “buy” symbol instead of play.
I could see all of his other games but I couldn’t play Arma 3.

He also wasn’t playing anything at the time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Certain games are excluded from Steam family sharing. Arma 3 is one of them. Unfortunately, this means if you want to play Arma 3 you will either have to buy it, or play it while logged into your friend's account.

[An (outdated) list of ineligible games can be found here](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/0/540732347100354802/)